# Can't set headers after they are sent...no issue until I added in authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, axios

I'm having some issues trying to send an axios requests with custom headers from my app so I can use them for authentication on my server.

I have a react native app that uses firebase authentication and a  node/express backend server.

When a user signs in, I will grab their firebase idtoken and store it.

I will then send that idtoken as a header whenever I  make an axios request to the server.

```
 const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();

  const url = ${serverUrl}/api/users/${user.uid`;

  const idtoken = await currentUser.getToken(true);

    var config = {
      headers: { idtoken },
    };

const response = await axios(url, config);
```

In the server code, there will be an express middleware that checks whether the idtoken sent in the request header is valid or not. If it is, it will call next() and proceed to execute the logic. If not, then it'll fail and send a 401 status.

This is in my `app.js`:

```
const app = express();


  app.use(bodyParser.json());

  app.use(firebaseAuthentication);
  router(app);
```

This is the `firebaseAuthentication` middleware:

```
const firebaseAuthentication = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req);
  try {
    const { idtoken } = req.headers;

    await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idtoken);
    next();
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(401).send({ error: 'Unauthorized request. Must be signed in via firebase' });
  }
};
```

This is the router:

```
module.exports = app => {

    app.get('/api/users/:firebaseUID', UserController.getUser);
}
```

The issue is that everything seems to go through until it tries to send the good data back to the user...but I get a `404` and a `Error:  Can't set headers after they are sent`

This is the specific request that is failing:

```
  async getUser(req, res, next) {
    const firebaseUID = req.params.firebaseUID;
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ firebaseUID });

      res.send(user);
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  },
```

What is happening here and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: do you get the correct data back when you log `response` also are you sure it gets authenticated, because it seems like it sends `401` first

Comment: Basically  this error comes when you have sent back a response prematurely. That is headers have already been sent back to the client from Node.

Comment: @82Tuskers you have a point, async might be the problem here, the function might throw as it is waiting for **auth**

Comment: if I `console.log(user)`, then it sends back exactly what it should do.

Comment: make sure you have app.use before app.get routes

Comment: Do include `more` code to debug this. The exact flow between the server's middleware (route handler and `next()`) presently seems unclear (to me).

Comment: `  app.use(firebaseAuthentication);
  router(app);
`

I have it in that order in my `app.js`. All of the routes are within the `router()`

Comment: Will add more code.

Comment: updated to add more code

Comment: @MattCleary did you try removing `async` here `async getUser(req, res, next) {...}`

Comment: Just tried that and used promises instead. No good :(

Comment: @MattCleary also I see that you have a more `next()` s . You have other middleware's too that will receive them ?

Comment: re: `and use promises instead? ` I don't think you need it. Can you try running it without ? Let me post it in the answer section and then may be I can interactively correct it.

Comment: How can I pass it onto the request handler if I don't call next?

Comment: Tried to take it off, but doesn't work, User.findOne() is async. It's connecting to my mongoDb

Comment: just removing my answer. Its a mess. My apologies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154084/discussion-between-82tuskers-and-matt-cleary).